# How to update rows based on select statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to update a column on certain rows returned by a subquery, using the following query. The subquery selects the right ids of the rows needing to be updated.

```
UPDATE 4_dev.Images AS Im
        SET Im.primary=1 
        WHERE EXISTS (
SELECT Img.imageId FROM (
SELECT I.id AS imageId,
       I.userId,
       I.date,
       SUM(I.primary) AS hasPrimary,
       COUNT(*) AS numImages
FROM 4_dev.Images AS I
GROUP BY I.userId
HAVING numImages>=1 AND hasPrimary=0) AS Img)
```

But this query updates every row, not just the rows in the SELECT subquery.

This would be easy to break into two pieces in PHP but I want to know how to update it with one query. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Change `WHERE EXISTS (`
to `WHERE Im.id IN (`

Answer (score 0):

you have a mistake in your query, you forgot define join condition between table which you try to update and statement in EXISTS

```
UPDATE 4_dev.Images AS Im
  SET Im.primary=1 
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT Img.imageId
  FROM (
    SELECT I.id AS imageId,
      I.userId,
      I.date,
      SUM(I.primary) AS hasPrimary,
      COUNT(*) AS numImages
    FROM 4_dev.Images AS I
    GROUP BY I.userId
    HAVING numImages>=1 AND hasPrimary=0) AS Img
    WHERE Img.imageId = Im.id)
```

furthermore your query is complicated. 
Unfortunatly I do not know your database structure, but looks like that you can simplify your query using UPDATE from multiple tables 
http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?20,85813,85813